# how to set direction in cell of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, direction

I have a gridview and bind to dataset for showing price in one column , price should seprated by "," and currency symbol at the end.

```
protected void gvAirWaybill_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
           double a = Convert.ToDouble(e.Row.Cells[11].Text.Trim());
           e.Row.Cells[11].Text = (a.ToString("C0", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fa-IR")));
    }
}
```

but it writes the symbol then price.how to set direction left to right just for this in runtime?

Comment: You asked how to set direction left to right! Did you mean right to left? because by default the direction is left to right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the Style attribute

```
e.Row.Cells[11].Style.Add("dir", "rtl");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set all the gridview as right to left, you can declare your gridview like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvAirWaybill" runat="server" dir="rtl" >
...
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CSS class

```
 .dir-rtl{
    direction:rtl;
}
```

Then in the grid markup set the Column's Item Style CssClass to that CSS class that you created

```
<ItemStyle CssClass="dir-rtl" />
```